# Matching with probabilistic edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider two sets $A,B$, each with $n$ vertices. For each pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$, the edge between $a$ and $b$ appears with probability $0.01$, independently of the remaining edges. Is it true that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the probability that there exists a matching between $A$ and $B$ approaches $1$?

I think it should be true, because for large $n$ the number of options that each vertex from $A$ has in $B$ grows. In particular, the number of options is roughly $0.01n$, and with high probability it is not far from that. [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) might help, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: This seems incomplete for the goal. If an edge appears, does it stay or how long does it stay? Or do you consider an infinity of events where the edges are selected at once?

Comment: @LutzL You can think of all the edges of being independently selected at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly true.

In fact, I believe it should be true if the probability $p$ of an edge, is, say $\frac{4\log n}{n}$. Erdos and Renyi probably proved such a threshold result for perfect matchings in general (i.e. not necessarily bipartite) graphs.

Now some justification: I'll use Hall's theorem and indicate why $|N(S)| \geq |S|$ is true for all sets $S \subset A$ with probability tending to 1.

Let $S$ be a fixed set of size $s$. Divide $B$ into $s$ sets of equal size. Fix an ordering on both $S$ and the sets of $B$ and consider a set of $s$ perfect matchings between them (pairwise disjoint). For each matching,  we'll try to find a neighbor for any element of $S$ in the corresponding set of $B$. The probability that this cannot be done for any matching is at most $s^s(1-p)^{st}$, where $t=\frac{n}{s}$. The probability that a bad $S$ exists is at most ${(\frac{en}{s})}^{s}s^se^{-pn}$, which goes to zero when $s<< \frac{n}{\log n}$.

If $n \leq 3s$, we can show that $N(S)=B$ with prob tending to 1. We have $ Pr[\exists S: |S|=s, N(S) \neq B] \leq {n \choose s}np^s \leq {(\dfrac{en}{s})}^sn(1-p)^s$; which goes to zero since $(1-p)^s$ dominates the other terms.

[To be continued...]

Comment: "and Chernoff bounds can be applied to show that all sets of size $s$ do satisfy Hall's condition. " Are you sure that this can hold simultaneously for *all* sets of size $s$? There are $\binom{n}{s}$ of them, and I'm not sure the bound from Chernoff is strong enough

Comment: Also, shouldn't your last line be $(1-p)^s$ instead of $p^s$?

Comment: I added some calculation depending on whether $s$ is small or large, but there is a gap and possibly I missed something.